# Undefined refference to glib when building lixml++ example on FreeBSD

Tags: c++, linker, freebsd, libxml2, glib

I'm trying to build example code from libxml++ on FreeBSD 10.1-RELEASE, but I'm getting `undefined reference to Glib::...` error when linking libraries.
On CentOS 6.5 and 7.0 is code compiled without errors.
When enabling linker verbose mode, it seems that all glib libraries are found.
I tried to reinstall glib libraries a few times but nothing changed.

Any suggestions why compilation fails?

Source code and makefile below.

main.cc:

> ```
> #include <libxml++/libxml++.h>
>
> #include <iostream>
>
> void print_indentation(unsigned int indentation) {
>         for (unsigned int i = 0; i < indentation; ++i)
>                 std::cout << " ";
> }
>
> void print_node(const xmlpp::Node* node, unsigned int indentation = 0) {
>         std::cout << std::endl; //Separate nodes by an empty line.
>
>         const xmlpp::ContentNode* nodeContent = dynamic_cast<const xmlpp::ContentNode*>(node);
>         const xmlpp::TextNode* nodeText = dynamic_cast<const xmlpp::TextNode*>(node);
>         const xmlpp::CommentNode* nodeComment = dynamic_cast<const xmlpp::CommentNode*>(node);
>
>         if (nodeText && nodeText->is_white_space()) //Let's ignore the indenting - you don't always want to do this.
>                 return;
>
>         Glib::ustring nodename = node->get_name();
>
>         if (!nodeText && !nodeComment && !nodename.empty()) //Let's not say "name: text".
>         {
>                 print_indentation(indentation);
>                 std::cout << "Node name = " << node->get_name() << std::endl;
>                 std::cout << "Node name = " << nodename << std::endl;
>         } else if (nodeText) //Let's say when it's text. - e.g. let's say what that white space is.
>         {
>                 print_indentation(indentation);
>                 std::cout << "Text Node" << std::endl;
>         }
>
>         //Treat the various node types differently: 
>         if (nodeText) {
>                 print_indentation(indentation);
>                 std::cout << "text = \"" << nodeText->get_content() << "\"" << std::endl;
>         } else if (nodeComment) {
>                 print_indentation(indentation);
>                 std::cout << "comment = " << nodeComment->get_content() << std::endl;
>         } else if (nodeContent) {
>                 print_indentation(indentation);
>                 std::cout << "content = " << nodeContent->get_content() << std::endl;
>         } else if (const xmlpp::Element* nodeElement = dynamic_cast<const xmlpp::Element*>(node)) {
>                 //A normal Element node:
>
>                 //line() works only for ElementNodes.
>                 print_indentation(indentation);
>                 std::cout << "     line = " << node->get_line() << std::endl;
>
>                 //Print attributes:
>                 const xmlpp::Element::AttributeList& attributes = nodeElement->get_attributes();
>                 for (xmlpp::Element::AttributeList::const_iterator iter = attributes.begin(); iter != attributes.end(); ++iter) {
>                         const xmlpp::Attribute* attribute = *iter;
>                         print_indentation(indentation);
>                         std::cout << "  Attribute " << attribute->get_name() << " = " << attribute->get_value() << std::endl;
>                 }
>
>                 const xmlpp::Attribute* attribute = nodeElement->get_attribute("title");
>                 if (attribute) {
>                         std::cout << "title found: =" << attribute->get_value() << std::endl;
>
>                 }
>         }
>
>         if (!nodeContent) {
>                 //Recurse through child nodes:
>                 xmlpp::Node::NodeList list = node->get_children();
>                 for (xmlpp::Node::NodeList::iterator iter = list.begin(); iter != list.end(); ++iter) {
>                         print_node(*iter, indentation + 2); //recursive
>                 }
>         }
> }
>
> int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
>         std::string filepath;
>         if (argc > 1)
>                 filepath = argv[1]; //Allow the user to specify a different XML file to parse.
>         else
>                 filepath = "example.xml";
>
>         try {
>                 xmlpp::DomParser parser;
>                 parser.set_validate();
>                 parser.set_substitute_entities(); //We just want the text to be resolved/unescaped automatically.
>                 parser.parse_file(filepath);
>                 if (parser) {
>                         //Walk the tree:
>                         const xmlpp::Node* pNode = parser.get_document()->get_root_node(); //deleted by DomParser.
>                         print_node(pNode);
>                 }
>         } catch (const std::exception& ex) {
>                 std::cout << "Exception caught: " << ex.what() << std::endl;
>         }
>
>         return 0;
> }
> ```

makefile:

> ```
> OBJDIR=.obj
>
> OBJS_MAIN = $(OBJDIR)/main.o
>
> OBJS_ALL = $(OBJS_MAIN)
>
> default: ao3
>
> CC = g++48
>
> #CENTOS_VERSION=$(shell sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]\).*/\1\2/' < /etc/redhat-release )
> CENTOS_VERSION=70
> CFLAGS_GS = -DWITH_OPENSSL -DWITH_GZIP -DWITH_CDATA -D CENTOS_VERSION=$(CENTOS_VERSION) -pthread
>
> #  -Wl,--verbose 
> OFLAGS= \
>   -Wl,--verbose \
>   -L/usr/local/lib \
>   -L "/usr/lib64/mysql" \
>   -L "/usr/lib/mysql" \
>   -L "/usr/local/lib/mysql" \
>   -L "/usr/lib64" \
>   -L "/usr/lib" \
>   -L "/usr/share/axiscpp/lib" \
>   -L "/usr/local/axis/lib" \
>   -L "/usr/local/lib/amadeus_2_1_39_5" \
>   -lboost_iostreams \
>   -lboost_date_time \
>   -lmysqlclient \
>   -lxml++-2.6 \
>   -lxml2 \
>   -lglibmm-2.4 \
>   -lgobject-2.0 \
>   -lgmodule-2.0 \
>   -lglib-2.0 \
>   -lloki \
>   -liconv\
>   -lpcre \
>   -lsigc-2.0 \
>   -lSockets \
>   -lssl \
>   -lintl \
>   -lffi \
>   -llzma \
>   -lpthread \
>   -lexpat \
>   -lbz2 \
>   -lglib \
>   -lz \
>   -luuid \
>   -lthr \
>   -lc++ \
>   -lm \
>   -lcxxrt \
>   -lgcc_s \
>   -lc
>
> ifeq ($(CENTOS_VERSION),65)
> OFLAGS += -lboost_system
> endif
>
> ifeq ($(CENTOS_VERSION),70)
> OFLAGS += -lboost_system
> OFLAGS += -lcrypto
> OFLAGS += -lboost_filesystem
> endif
>
> EXTCFLAGS := -g
>
> LDFLAGS= -L/usr/local/lib
>
> #  -Weffc++ 
> CFLAGS= $(EXTCFLAGS) \
>   -Wall \
>   -Werror \
>   -Wextra \
>   -D LARGEFILE64_SOURCE \
>   -D FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 \
>   -D _UP_UNIX_ \
>   -D CNT_VERSION=2_3 \
>   -D LOKI_OBJECT_LEVEL_THREADING \
>   -D CENTOS_VERSION=$(CENTOS_VERSION) \
>   -isystem"/usr/include/" \
>   -isystem"/usr/local/include/" \
>   -isystem"/usr/include/libxml++-2.6" \
>   -isystem"/usr/local/include/libxml++-2.6" \
>   -isystem"/usr/local/include/libxml++-2.6/include" \
>   -isystem"/usr/lib/libxml++-2.6/include" \
>   -isystem"/usr/local/lib/libxml++-2.6/include" \
>   -isystem"/usr/lib64/libxml++-2.6/include" \
>   -isystem"/usr/include/glibmm-2.4" \
>   -isystem"/usr/local/include/glibmm-2.4" \
>   -isystem"/usr/lib/glibmm-2.4/include" \
>   -isystem"/usr/local/lib/glibmm-2.4/include" \
>   -isystem"/usr/lib64/glibmm-2.4/include" \
>   -isystem"/usr/local/include/glib-2.0/" \
>   -isystem"/usr/include/glib-2.0/" \
>   -isystem"/usr/lib/glib-2.0/include" \
>   -isystem"/usr/local/lib/glib-2.0/include" \
>   -isystem"/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include" \
>   -isystem"/usr/lib/glib/include" \
>   -isystem"/usr/lib64/glib/include" \
>   -isystem"/usr/local/include/glib-1.2" \
>   -isystem"/usr/include/mysql" \
>   -isystem"/usr/local/include/mysql"
>
> $(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cc
>         @mkdir -p $(@D)
>         $(CC) -MMD -MP -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@   $<
>         @echo -n '.' >>  "$(DOTSFILE)"
>         @curr=`wc -c < $(DOTSFILE)`; max=`cat $(MAXFILE)`; echo -e "\033[1m$$curr/$$max\033[0m"
>
> $(OBJDIR)/main.o: main.cc
>         @mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)
>         $(CC) -MMD -MP -c $(CFLAGS) $(INCLUDE) -o $@   $<
>
> -include $(OBJS_ALL:.o=.d)
>
> DOTSFILE := /dev/null
> MAXFILE := /dev/null
>
> help:
>         @echo 'ao3, test, profile, clean, cleantest, cleanprofile'
>         @echo 'CentOS version: '$(CENTOS_VERSION)
>
> ao3: $(OBJS_ALL)
>         $(CC) --verbose -o ao3 -Wl,--start-group $(OBJS_ALL) $(OFLAGS) -Wl,--end-group
>
> test: $(OBJS_TEST_ALL)
>         $(CC) -o ao3_test $(OBJS_TEST_ALL) $(OFLAGS)
>
> profile: $(OBJS_PROFILE_ALL)
>         $(CC) -o ao3_profile $(OBJS_PROFILE_ALL) $(OFLAGS)
>
> clean:
>         rm -f $(wildcard $(OBJS_ALL) ao3 $(OBJS_ALL:.o=.d))
>         find $(OBJDIR) -type d -empty -delete
>
> cleantest:
>         rm -f $(wildcard $(OBJS_TEST) ao3_test $(OBJS_TEST:.o=.d))
>         find $(OBJDIR) -type d -empty -delete
>
> cleanprofile:
>         rm -f $(wildcard $(OBJS_PROFILE) ao3_profile $(OBJS_PROFILE:.o=.d))
>         find $(OBJDIR) -type d -empty -delete
> ```

Comment: undefined references to `Glib::what exactly`? I suspect you're using symbols that appeared in a later version of glibmm than comes with FreeBSD.

Comment: undefined references are:
`undefined reference to Glib::operator<<(std::ostream&, Glib::ustring const&)'
undefined reference to 'Glib::ustring::ustring(std::string const&)'`

Comment: version of glibmm is 2.4 on CentOS systems as well as on FreeBSD

Comment: It's not 2.4 on any of them; that's just the oldest version to which it is ABI-backwards-compatible. If I read the package lists correctly, CentOS 6.5 has glibmm 2.22 while CentOS 7 and FreeBSD 10 have 2.36. The symbols it mentions should be present in all of those versions, though. Hmm...does anything change if you `#include <string>` at the top of main.cc?

Comment: Didn't know that thanks for pointing it out. glibmm version on FreeBSD is 2.42.0. Compilation fails the same way with `#include <string>`

Comment: libxml++ comes with a pkg-config file. Maybe try to add the output of pkg-config libxml++1.0 --libs to the Linker flags

Comment: I tried pkg-config for libxml++ and glibmm, but the problem is still the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the problem is that glibmm is compiled by clang and I'm using gcc for compilation. When c++ is used instead of g++48 for compilation it works fine.